# Zend Autoloader.php file missing?

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework2

I'm using a Wordpress plugin [Zend Framework for wordpress](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/zend-framework-wp) and I'm downloading the actual Zend library to plug it into the plugin (it doesn't provide by itself) from http://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives

Error:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\localhost\~\wp-content\plugins\zend-framework-wp\zend-framework.php on line 28
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear;C:\localhost\~\wp-content\plugins\zend-framework-wp') in C:\localhost\~\wp-content\plugins\zend-framework-wp\zend-framework.php on line 28
```

zend-framework.php, line 28

```
function zend_framework_register_autoload()
{
    require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
}
```

There's no `Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php`.

[image: Path: C:\localhost\~\wp-content\plugins\zend-framework-wp\Zend\Loader]

There's a `AutoloaderFactory.php`, `StandardAutoloader.php`... I tried renaming them to `Autoloader.php` but ran into more errors,

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Loader_Autoloader' not found in C:\localhost\~\wp-content\plugins\zend-framework-wp\zend-framework.php on line 29
```

I guess that's not the way to go.

What's going wrong?

edit: I've [cross-posted to wordpress.stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98363/zend-autoloder-php-file-missing)

Comment: There is simply NO SINGLE NEED to include the Framework as a Plugin. Download the Framework itself and add it to your `include_path`. And then follow [ZF2 Autoloading instructions](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/using-zendloaderautoloader/)

Comment: `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` and its singleton implementation are part of `Zend Framework 1`. Looking at your directory structure and the tags of this question you are trying to autload ZF2. Make sure you are using what you need :)